# How to show MySql query recordset into datagridview

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I'm pretty new to vb.net and I'm trying to show the result of a query into a datagridview.

In VBA I was able to show it into a listbox with a simple command:

```
MyArray = rs.GetRows
'Then, after transposing of array
Me.ListBox1.List = MyArray
```

This doesn't seems to work on vb.net and using a DataGridView seems to be the easiest solution. (If it's simpler to use listbox please show me the way)

This is code I wrote. It doesn't give errors but nothing is showed in the gridview. Looking around I've read something about "bind" but every attempt of using it is failed.

```
    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Server_Name, Database_Name, UserDB, Password, SQLStr As String
    Dim mRS_Result As Object

    Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Server_Name = "localhost" 
    Database_Name = "MyDBName" 
    UserDB = "root" 
    Password = "" 

    Cn.Open("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=" & Server_Name & _
        ";Database=" & Database_Name & ";Uid=" & UserDB & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";")
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM errlog WHERE Data > NOW()-100000"
    rs.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
    rs.Open(SQLStr, Cn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic)
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then mRS_Result = rs.GetRows()

    Me.DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = rs
```

Comment: You need to scrap the VBA approach and do it the .net way. Download the   mysql .net driver: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.0.html and start reading the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html You should also look at the .net naming guidelines: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx Oh, and set the strict compiler option ON: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå You're right and I wanna do so, but my knowledge is limited and I don't speak english so well. I need to go a small step at time: First: the code to work; second: improving the code. Someone says me: "Better" is enemy of "good".

Comment: Taking one step at a time is fine as long as you go in the right direction. As is, you're going in the wrong direction. Here's a step-by-step guide: http://www.ownedcore.com/forums/general/programming/302420-mysql-connection-datagridview-vb-net.html

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Thanks! I'll read it with pleasure